# Embed youtube video with source from database

Tags: php, html, youtube

```
<iframe width="277" height="250" src="<?php $results['url'] ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

As above code I am trying to embed YouTube video on my site with the Embed URL coming from my query. The `$results['url']` returns a valid Embedding URL.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: ..and the question is?

Comment: so what is the problem???

Comment: Since you don't actually specify a question, I'm not entirely sure of what you want, but you at least need to `echo` or `print` your result to have a source: `<?php echo $results['url']; ?>`

Comment: Just realised how stupid I am. My question was why is it not embedding a video but as user above said I didnt write echo *facepalm*